# Scroll window then div, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am struggling with jQuery to write a code, which let me obtain the effect like in my example. I am doing this because scrollIntoView works properly only in Chrome.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lw6b88wg/1/

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    let listElements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
    let lastElementNumber = listElements.length;
    listElements[lastElementNumber - 1].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'end',
        inline: 'end'
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to achive scrollTop on button click?

Comment: @pmaddi scroll to window top, then scroll to div bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  var divHeight = $('#outer-div')[0].scrollHeight;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: '0px'
  }, 300);
  $('#outer-div').animate({
    scrollTop: divHeight
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-div">
  <p>
    1
  </p>
  <p>
    2
  </p>
  <p>
    3
  </p>
  <p>
    4
  </p>
  <p>
    5
  </p>
  <p>
    6
  </p>
  <p>
    7
  </p>
  <p>
    8
  </p>
  <p>
    9
  </p>
  <p>
    10
  </p>
  <p>
    11
  </p>
  <p>
    12
  </p>
  <p>
    13
  </p>
</div>
<button id="btn">
click me
</button >
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great. It works almost as I wanted. I only inserted $('#outer-div').animate into  $('html, body').animate callback.